# Spring Data Gemfire: How to set TTL for entry using annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I am trying to set timeout for 30 days (i.e. 2592000 seconds) for entries in a region.

In, gfsh I was able to do `create region --name=employee --type=REPLICATE --enable-statistics --entry-time-to-live-expiration=2592000`. To confirm, do we use `@TimeToLiveExpiration` for entry not for region. I do not want the region to be deleted. If this is for entry then curious how can we set for region? Thanks.

```
@ReplicatedRegion(name = "employee") 
@EnableStatistics 
@TimeToLiveExpiration(timeout = "2592000", action = "DESTROY") // is this for region or entry ?? 
@Data
public class Employee {
   private String id; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both SDG's entity-level Expiration-based annotations, `@TimeToLiveExpiration` and `@IdleTimeoutExpiration` configure `Region` "entry" level expiration polices.

Technically, this is [implemented](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/main/spring-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/expiration/AnnotationBasedExpiration.java#L69) as an `CustomExpiry` object ([*Javadoc*](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/CustomExpiry.html)) registered on the `Region` (e.g. "*employees*"). These annotations most definitely do NOT expire, or delete/remove the `Region`.

More information on configuring Apache Geode (GemFire) Expiration (policies) using SDG can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap:region:expiration:annotation) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-region-expiration).